# Drupal 7 - Remove checkboxes in first column of tables

Tags: drupal, form-api

So I have wrote a simple table in my .admin.inc file :

```
<?php
  $form["myfieldset"]["mytable"] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $headers,
    '#options' => $rows,
  );
?>
```

And I have all the data I want in it, but the first column of the table has checkboxes whereas I don't want any...
Is it possible to remove them?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the functionality provided by a tableselect element, the question has to be asked...why are you using a tableselect element?

It would make a lot more sense to use [`theme_table()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) if you just want a bog standard HTML table:

```
$form['myfieldset']['mytable'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows
);
```

Comment: Well, really thank you dude that was exactly the option I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Test this :

```
<?php
  $form["myfieldset"]["mytable"] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $headers,
    '#options' => $rows,
    '#disabled' => TRUE
  );
?>
```

Have you try to add custom CSS like this :

```
.form-radios .form-disabled {
  display: none;
}
```